# Overloading operator T***()

Tags: c++, struct, operator-overloading

I don't know, why my code doesn't work. I create `struct` and inside put overloading operator`operator T***()`, In main I'd like using following notation `const int * const * const * p1 = a;`

```
struct A{
    template<class T> operator T***(){}
};

int main(){
    A a;
    const int * const * const * p1 = a;
    return 0;
}
```

`Error: undefined reference to '_ZN1AcvPPPT_IKiEEv'`

Comment: I have no idea why you expected that to work.

Comment: @sjdowling: Tell him why.

Comment: Of all the weird code i've seen on SO, this made me go WTF the most. Congrats :) Seriously, though, what are you trying to achieve here?

Comment: you havent written the code for the T*** function

Comment: @sjdowling the code is fine though.

Comment: please edit the question and say why you are doing this - we are all dying to know

Comment: Your last edit of the question changed it dramatically. Does your code have `operator T***();` or `operator T***(){}`? All the answers are to the question while it had the former, and changing that invalidates them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You simply missed to give your type conversion function an implementation

```
struct A{
    template<class T> operator T***() {
        return nullptr; // Do whatever you want to do here.
    }
};
```

See a [working sample](http://ideone.com/jp1DRY) please.

Comment: Damn chaining of const :)

Comment: @Shan As you can see from the linked sample, `const` doesn't play any role here.

Answer (score 2):

I have absolutely no idea what you are trying to do, but your problem is a linker problem. You just declare (but not define) the conversion operator `T***`. You have to define it,

```
template<class T> operator T***()
{ 
   // define it here
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Before you edited the question:

```
template<class T> operator T***();
```

declares the operator template, but doesn't define it, hence the error that it's undefined. You'll get that error even if you define the template in another source file, since templates must be defined in every translation unit that uses them.

After the edit:

```
template<class T> operator T***(){}
```

the code compiles, but has undefined behaviour since the operator is missing a return statement.